# Inserting multiple items with Web.Config transforms

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-config-transform

I've got a C# project that references a lot of WCF services. For local testing, I want to replace the contents of the identity tags so that it will accept anything running on localhost.

The following transformation works, but only inserts the dns element in the first matching location. So, if I had 5 endpoints referenced, one would have the dns tag, and the others would all have empty identity elements.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint>
        <identity>
          <dns xdt:Transform="Insert" value="localhost"/>
          <userPrincipalName xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" value="someIdentity" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

How do I alter all of the matching elements, not just the first?

Comment: are you trying to remove all `<userPrincipalName>` elements?

Comment: Yes, and that part works fine. However, I also want to replace those <userPrincipalName> elements with <dns>, and I have failed to do so. I've worked around this by actually listing all of the endpoints manually, but if there's a more elegant solution I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `xdt:Locator` attribute to define an XPath expression to match all `<identity>` elements that you want to insert into.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint>
        <identity xdt:Locator="XPath(//identity)">
          <dns xdt:Transform="Insert" value="localhost"/>
          <userPrincipalName xdt:Transform="RemoveAll"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Browsing the source code at http://xdt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#XmlTransform/XmlTransforms.cs leads me to conclude that this is not currently supported