# Web.config with XDT transform to do partial replace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web-config, .net-4.5, web.config-transform

I am in a situation where I just want to update a part of a the URL of a WCF endpoint. Right now we do this by including different configs with all the endpoints per 'variety'. This is tedious to manage. I would like to setup a transform in the web.config to do so.

These are two examples of the files

**Dev**

```
  <endpoint address="http://servicesdev.host.com/RPUtilityServices/LogException.svc/restService"
        behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="Host.RP.Shared.Common.Services.Utility.Interfaces.IExceptionUtilityService"
        name="LogService" />
```

and some more of these

**Staging**

```
  <endpoint address="http://servicessta.host.com/RPUtilityServices/LogException.svc/restService"
            behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="Host.RP.Shared.Common.Services.Utility.Interfaces.IExceptionUtilityService"
            name="LogService" />
```

The difference is the servicessta versus servicesdev. Now I also have servicesuat and a servicesqa etcera. I would like to setup a transform to just replace the '**dev**' with '**sta**' etc and not the entire block (using `xdt:Transform="Replace"`)

But how do I do that?

Comment: Just curious what do you gain by replacing a substring of the url instead of entire attribute?

Comment: I have a few more blocks like that, restService, the soap one etc. What I would gain is that I need to update just one file to replace the service address instead of all other files. We have 5 environments, so the replaces make the management easier.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your post. I thought you wanted to run some sort of substring on the attribute when you really just wanted to change just the attribute (at least that is what I am getting from the answer you marked as correct).

Comment: No, you are right in that I wanted just the substring replacement. It is just impossible so I accepted the answer as correct as it is the next best alternative.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first piece of code above (for dev environment) can go to `Web.config` (or `Web.debug.config` but have to add `xdt` transform as well). In your `Web.release.config` (this one will go to staging environment) define the following element.

```
<endpoint address="http://servicessta.host.com/RPUtilityServices/LogException.svc/restService"
        behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="Host.RP.Shared.Common.Services.Utility.Interfaces.IExceptionUtilityService"
        name="LogService" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

Note that I added **xdt:Transform="Replace"** in the release config file. With this attribute present the settings defined within the `endpoint` element will replace those in your base `Web.config` file.

For more information see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

Using the `xdt:Transform="Replace"` would replace the entire `<endpoint />` element. To selectively replace the `address` attribute of the `<endpoint />` element use the following transform.

```
<endpoint address="http://servicessta.host.com/RPUtilityServices/LogException.svc/restService"
 xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)"/>
```

(Note that if there are several `<endpoint />` elements you might want to use the **Locator** attribute as well.)

What I said is described in detail on the MSDN page I posted above.

Comment: I am familiar with how to do a replace on a node (with xdt:Transform="Replace"). I want to only replace a part of the string so I do not have that redefinition everywhere.

Comment: Can you please show an example with multiple endpoints and the `Locator` attribute? Nm, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637107/web-config-transformation-how-to-apply-a-transformation-to-all-node-matching-a

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. This is not a substring replacement.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked which was to replace only part of the string, not the entire string.

Comment: This does not answer the question.